# Problem with rollup dev server crashing in svelte 3

Tags: svelte, rollup, rollupjs, svelte-3

I have setup svelte with degit.
The dev server is started with
`rollup -c -w`
I made no modifications to any of the files.

But in the ./public/ folder, I have a large folder with many subfolders with images and json files (>2GB). Those files contain posts which I want to later fetch into the SPA running svelte.

When I start the dev server, the command just stops without error messages:

> $ npm run dev
>
> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
> rollup -c -w
>
> rollup v2.60.0
> bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
>
> $

I can verify that the large folder in ./public/ is the problem. When I move it somewhere else, the dev server starts.

I suspect this is caused by the plugin rollup-plugin-livereload which attempts to watch the public folder for changes. There are too many files in the subfolder, so itruns out of memory and crashes.

How can I configure rollup-plugin-livereload to exclude a subfolder in the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

`livereload` plugin accepts a `watch` property in its options object, whose value may be of type string or array. So you could try to update the rollup.config.js with something like:

```
livereload(
  { watch: ['public/', 'public/build/'] }
)
```